# How to change a variable's value inside a function and the value to be returned when the function is called?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Picture this situation: I have **3** files: `file1.py`, `file2.py` and `file3.py`. All the files are under the same package (possibly in different folders). Inside `file1.py` there is a function called `getter()` which has some local variable inside of it and the function returns its value when it is called. `getter()` is allowed to accept parameters if needed to set the value of that variable. During runtime, I want to set the value of that local variable by calling `getter()` from `file2.py`, such that whenever the `getter()` function is called from `file3.py` I get the latest set value from it. How to achieve it? Please note that the value is supposed to be updated multiple times, for each time `file3.py` should get the latest set value.

For demonstration, following is a draft presentation of what I want:

[image: demo]

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Can you provide us with more detail?

Comment: It sounds like you need to either make the variable a member of the module not the function or have a class that contains the variable as well as the getters and setters and have an instance of that class created in the module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `global` in `file1.py` which is set and returned by `file1.getter()`. The `val` needs to be an optional argument so that when getter is *called to retrieve the value*, it can be called without passing a value for `val`.

```py
# in file1.py
_REAL_VAL = 10  # initial default value

def getter(val=None):
    global _REAL_VAL
    if val is not None:
        # set
        _REAL_VAL = val
    # get, or set+get
    return _REAL_VAL
```

The underscore `_` before the name implies "internal use"/"private" so that other modules should not try to access or change it directly.

(And if you don't want it to return the value when it's being *set*, then put `return _REAL_VAL` in an `else:` clause. It will still implicitly return `None` as all Python functions would when there's no return value.)

---

Edit: Btw, "setting" with a "getter" is bad/silly. Use a [`property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) instead - which requires creating a class. You'll still maintain the instance globally.

```py
# in file1.py

class Value:
    def __init__(self):
        self._val = None  # the real value

    @property
    def val(self):
        return self._val

    @val.setter
    def val(self, value):
        self._val = value


# is only executed once when imported
getter = Value()  # terrible name


# in file2.py, set it
file1.getter.val = 10

# in file3.py, get it
print(file1.getter.val)
# 10
```

It will be the same/only one instance of `Value` (`getter`) because the `import file1` [will only be executed once](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#more-on-modules), even if imported many times:

> A module can contain executable statements as well as function definitions. These statements are intended to initialize the module. They are executed only the *first* time the module name is encountered in an import statement. (They are also run if the file is executed as a script.)

Comment: @hafiz031 Btw, since the class `Value` is only meant to be used in `file1.py`, it should be marked as "private" and named `_Value`.

Comment: Thank you, I have a small question - are the above implementations thread-safe?

Comment: @hafiz031 No, it's not thread-safe. You'll need to use [locks](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#lock-objects), etc. to get it work properly with threads.